# grouping rows with less than one minute separating row from previous row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, gaps-and-islands

I have an Oracle table with time stamps and I need to check on all rows where the current row is bigger the the previous row by less than a minute and state the start and end time and if its bigger than a minute I need to start a new group as in the example below. (The table is ordered in ASC time

I have the table

| ID | TIME (TIME STAMP) |
| --- | --- |
|  | 11:33:03 |
|  | 11:34:01 |
|  | 11:34:40 |
|  | 11:35:59 |
|  | 11:38:00 |
|  | 11:38:50 |

I need to pull

| Group number | start time | end time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11:33:03 | 11:34:40 |
| 2 | 11:35:59 | 11:35:59 |
| 3 | 11:38:00 | 11:38:50 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT id,
       grp,
       MIN(time) AS start_time,
       MAX(time) AS end_time
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         time,
         SUM(grp_change) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) AS grp
  FROM   (
    SELECT t.*,
           CASE
           WHEN time - LAG(time) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) <= INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
           END AS grp_change
    FROM   table_name t
  )
)
GROUP BY id, grp;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, TIME) AS
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2022-06-14 11:33:03' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2022-06-14 11:34:01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2022-06-14 11:34:40' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2022-06-14 11:35:59' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2022-06-14 11:38:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2022-06-14 11:38:50' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | GRP | START_TIME | END_TIME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2 | 2022-06-14 11:35:59.000000000 | 2022-06-14 11:35:59.000000000 |
> | 1 | 3 | 2022-06-14 11:38:00.000000000 | 2022-06-14 11:38:50.000000000 |
> | 1 | 1 | 2022-06-14 11:33:03.000000000 | 2022-06-14 11:34:40.000000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=37a64def1d914c8cf80c18a1f7707245)*